# Error while implementing a Kivy App with Splash Screen

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, splash-screen

I am implementing a GUI based application in Python 3 with Kivy. My app needs to have 2 screens. First one is a Splash Screen that stays for 5 seconds and then the second screen must come up. Second screen is Garden FileBrowser by Kivy.

I tried to implement this as shown below..

```
class PgSplash(Screen):


    def skip(self, dt):
        screen.switch_to(pages[1])

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.skip, 5)


class PgBrowser(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        user_path = os.path.join(browser_base.get_home_directory(), 'Documents')
        browser = browser_base.FileBrowser(select_string='Select',
                              favorites=[(user_path, 'Documents')])
        browser.bind(on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
                     on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled,
                     on_submit=self._fbrowser_submit)

        self.add_widget(browser)


    def _fbrowser_canceled(self, instance):
        print('cancelled, Close self.')
        self.root_window.hide()
        sys.exit(0)


    def _fbrowser_success(self, instance): # select pressed
        global file

        print(instance.selection)

        file = instance.selection[0]


    def _fbrowser_submit(self, instance): # clicked on the file
        global file

        print(instance.selection)

        file = instance.selection[0]

pages = [PgSplash(name="PgSplash"),
             PgBrowser(name="PgBrowser")]

screen = ScreenManager()
screen.add_widget(pages[0])


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen.current = "PgSplash"
        return screen

myApp().run()
```

While running this the Splash Screen comes up and the program crashes giving an error as shown below..

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 836, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:12509)
 KeyError: 'icon_view'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Spectre/Desktop/Project/base.py", line 219, in <module>
     myApp().run()
   File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 581, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 367, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy\_clock.c:7700)
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 397, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy\_clock.c:7577)
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 395, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy\_clock.c:7498)
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick (kivy\_clock.c:3490)
   File "C:\Users\Spectre\Desktop\Project\browser_base.py", line 320, in _post_init
     self.ids.icon_view.bind(selection=partial(self._attr_callback, 'selection'),
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:12654)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

What is the issue.? What is that I am doing wrong.? How to fix this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

I am able to get the app working by doing the following and removed ***self.root_window.hide()*** because "*AttributeError: 'PgBrowser' object has no attribute 'root_window'*". My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Python 3.5, and Kivy 1.10.0

### Snippets

```
class PgBrowser(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        if sys.platform == 'win':
            user_path = dirname(expanduser('~')) + sep + 'Documents'
        else:
            user_path = expanduser('~') + sep + 'Documents'
        browser = FileBrowser(select_string='Select',
                              favorites=[(user_path, 'Documents')])
```

## Example

### main.py

```
import sys
from os.path import sep, expanduser, dirname
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.garden.filebrowser import FileBrowser

file = ""


class PgSplash(Screen):
    def skip(self, dt):
        self.manager.current = "PgBrowser"

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.skip, 5)


class PgBrowser(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        if sys.platform == 'win':
            user_path = dirname(expanduser('~')) + sep + 'Documents'
        else:
            user_path = expanduser('~') + sep + 'Documents'
        browser = FileBrowser(select_string='Select',
                              favorites=[(user_path, 'Documents')])
        browser.bind(on_success=self._fbrowser_success,
                     on_canceled=self._fbrowser_canceled,
                     on_submit=self._fbrowser_submit)
        self.add_widget(browser)

    def _fbrowser_canceled(self, instance):
        print('cancelled, Close self.')
        sys.exit(0)

    def _fbrowser_success(self, instance):  # select pressed
        global file
        print(instance.selection)
        file = instance.selection[0]

    def _fbrowser_submit(self, instance):   # clicked on the file
        global file
        print(instance.selection)
        file = instance.selection[0]


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyScreenManager>:
    PgSplash:
    PgBrowser:

<PgSplash>:
    name: 'PgSplash'
    AnchorLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'kivyLogo.png'
            size_hint: 1,1

<PgBrowser>:
    name: 'PgBrowser'
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Splash Screen]
[image: Img02 - FileBrowser]
[image: Img03 - Selection]